# Spark extract single property from json using from_json function

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with one of column contains json string, which has dynamic schema and size of each json document can vary vastly. however each document includes a header info in front of the document which we want to use to parse and process the json based on some values inside the header.

The question i have is if we pass in schema only to read few properties from the json is from_json function optimized to skip over properties/arrays if they are not part of the schema. in our case "data" array can be very large and i am trying to figure out what is the most optimal way to reading just the header info.

```
    # Create Schema of the JSON column
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    from pyspark.sql import *
    json = """{
        "header": {
            "someguid": "B65A234E-4702-4561-90C9-2D3A403C7472",
            "code": "Hello",
            "some_number": 1
        },

        "id": "someservice@somehost",
        "serializer": "json",
        "propA" : "test",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    }
    """
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(json=json)])
    
    schema = StructType([
            StructField('header', StructType([
                StructField("someguid",StringType(),True), 
                StructField("code",StringType(),True),        
                StructField("some_number", IntegerType(), True)
                 ])) ])
         
    
    dfJSON = df.withColumn("jsonData",from_json(col("json"),schema)) \
                      .select("jsonData.*").select("header.*")
    dfJSON.printSchema()
    dfJSON.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance of `from_json` could vary depending on the size and complexity of the JSON document. If the JSON document is huge and have more added complexity  it might take longer time to compute and parse the elements even if you are reading small part of the data. 
So in order to handle such bottlenecks you could try something as below -

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

def parse_json(json_string):
    json_data = json.loads(json_string)
    header = json_data['header']
    return header

schema = StructType([
    StructField('someguid', StringType(), True),
    StructField('code', StringType(), True),
    StructField('some_number', IntegerType(), True),
])

parse_json_udf = udf(parse_json, schema)

df2 = df.withColumn("header",parse_json_udf(col('json'))).select("header.*")

df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```

Below are the screenshots to give a high level overview of the compute runtime (ran both in databricks) -

**Time taken by your code**
[image]

**Time taken by my code**
[image: Time taken by my code]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a fair comparison, since `spark.createDataFrame` is a relatively expensive action and the time is included in the first block time calculation. Also, I think more test case is needed to prove that your UDF could be faster than Spark API, since it's a heavy workload of serialization and deserialization between Python interpreter and JVM, especially when the json string is a column of a DataFrame and it's a bulky string.

Comment: using UDF might not be a good idea due to concerns around serialization of workload between JVM and python as point out by Jonathan.